# how to format dates for SOAP call

Tags: java, json, soap, apache-axis, axis

In Eclipse I created a SOAP client by right clicking the WSDL and going to Web Services > Generate client

This client is one of our communicator library and has worked good for some time now for all of the soap methods exposed.  However we recently found an issue with one call due to how dates are represented

Server is expecting
2007-01-01T00:00:00

But we are sending (including the ms)
2007-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

These values are for a Date [type] field called `validFrom` within an object called `TimeZoneRule` within the client

How can I properly format the date when making the SOAP call?

Comment: Which library is your client using for creating and sending SOAP envelopes? Axis2, CXF? With axis2 you can write a handler to change particular node in your SOAP message. Some example provided here: http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/writing-simple-axis2-handler.html

Comment: its in the tags, axis2, thank you ill check it out